# Get average color of UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to do something similar to what Twitter and many other apps do - set the background to the average color of an image. The problem is that based on the array of images that I have, it gets the last average color and it's never being changed. The background color for the `UIScrollView` in which those images are located. I'm not sure why.

This is the code that I'm using to extract the average color (PS: I found it [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-read-the-average-color-of-a-uiimage-using-ciareaaverage))

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    var averageColor: UIColor? {
        guard let inputImage = CIImage(image: self) else { return nil }
        let extentVector = CIVector(x: inputImage.extent.origin.x, y: inputImage.extent.origin.y, z: inputImage.extent.size.width, w: inputImage.extent.size.height)

        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaAverage", withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: inputImage, kCIInputExtentKey: extentVector]) else { return nil }
        guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else { return nil }

        var bitmap = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
        let context = CIContext(options: [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: kCFNull])
        context.render(outputImage, toBitmap: &bitmap, rowBytes: 4, bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), format: kCIFormatRGBA8, colorSpace: nil)

        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(bitmap[0]) / 255, green: CGFloat(bitmap[1]) / 255, blue: CGFloat(bitmap[2]) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(bitmap[3]) / 255)
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the function that's being called in the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    func setScrollView() {
    for  i in stride(from: 0, to: imagelist.count, by: 1) {
        var frame = CGRect.zero
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
        frame.origin.y = 0
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

        let newUIImageView = UIImageView()
        let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: imagelist[i])!
        let bgColorFromImage = myImage.averageColor
        newUIImageView.image = myImage
        newUIImageView.frame =  frame

        newUIImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

        scrollView.backgroundColor = bgColorFromImage // Changes the color to the average color of the image
        scrollView.addSubview(newUIImageView)

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(imagelist.count), height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changePage), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to create an array of `UIColor`s to store all of the colors of the images:

```
var colors = [UIColor]()
```

Then in `setScrollView()` append the color like so:

```
colors.append(myImage.averageColor!)
```

And lastly, in the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` set the background like so:

```
scrollView.backgroundColor = colors[Int(pageNumber)]
```